# How to define the attention tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I notice there is an [attention](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attention) and I have provided a tentative tag wiki.

> Questions relating to a child's ability to maintain attention Or the attention seeking behaviors.  The challenges of increasing children's focus and attention span. Many problems derive from attention seeking behavior and a child seeking attention.

I am wondering if people want attention to include seeking attention and improving a child's attention.

Comment: Just wanted to add, I edited a lot of posts that only had one tag and where I thought more tags were warranted to help searchability. I know it bumps a lot of posts, but I'm thinking in the longer run it will help search results. I hope people are ok with this. I won't do it again.

Comment: The retagging edits I've seen from you so far are generally spot-on.  However, the active question feed has become flooded.  Such mass edits shouldn't be done without prior meta discussion; generally, you shouldn't edit more than 5-10 questions at a time (I've been chastised on other sites for editing as few as 6 old questions at a time).

Comment: @Beofett sorry, won't do it again

Comment: No need to apologize; the questions definitely needed retagging.  I've done the same on other sites (and got suitably chastised).  There are some times we do massive edits (ask Torben about the time we went through 100% of the questions here and fixed all the titles!), but we try to coordinate those efforts with at least a warning on meta to explain what is happening and why.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed the one question with [attention](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attention) also has [focus](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/focus).

That question is the only one with either tag.

While there is a distinction between "attention" and "focus", I feel it is too fine of a distinction to merit separate tags.

I'm really not sure we need *either* tag.  It feels too granular.  I believe [behavior](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior) or [learning](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) (or both) would be more appropriate for the vast majority of questions touching upon attention or focus.

I think both tags should be removed.

Comment: ok, do you want me to remove them? Or shall you

Comment: Let's wait and let some other people chime in or vote.  There's no hurry, and this is just my opinion, which may not be shared by everyone :)

Comment: Oky doky.. :) and sorry about the edits (I mean too many of them)

Comment: Unless someone posts a contrary answer that gets some upvotes, I think you can go ahead with the edit reasonably soon.

Comment: Totally agree!  Attention-seeking stuff is a "behavior" issue and if it is about focus and attention, it is likely to fall into the ADD category (which has a tag I believe).  If it is about attention in a toddler, it still probably fits nicely into Behavior and Toddler tags.